# I don't know why (*p)=38; returns an error

Tags: c

I can't find any errors in the code below, but every time I run it, the compiler (Xcode) returns hread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10000a025). I'm wondering if any of you have any answers to the problem.

```
int main(){
    int *p,b;
    b=3;
    (*p)=38;
    b=(*p)+10;
    *p=b+1;
    printf("b,p=%d %d\n",b,*p);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you think `p` points at when you do that?

Comment: p is unassigned. Therefore you are assigning the value 38 to a random place in memory since p is uninitialized. Don't really understand why you are using p as a pointer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to dereference an uninitialized variable. Initialize it and it will work.

For example:

```
int *p,b,c=38;
b=3;
p=&c;
// now you can dereference it because it is initialized.
// now when you do (*p) = 3; // you will be changing c to 3
```

Or you can do this:

```
int *p; 
if (!(p=malloc(sizeof(*p))) return 1; // In case of failure of malloc

(*p) = 38; // valid
// you will also need to free the memory when you are done
free(p);
```

Comment: @PabloVizcaino no problem. I am glad that I could help you. If my answer helped you please mark it as the answer to your question.

Comment: Upvoted for the first version, but `int *p = new int () ;` isn't C.

Comment: @bhristov The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: It's not "another way to initialize it" in C, which is what the OP is writing in, so it's not another way to initialize it. In C, you'd have to use malloc.

Comment: The code in the other snippet is not syntactically valid C.

Comment: @user4815162342 I corrected it. I am sorry about that.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I corrected it. I am sorry about that.

Comment: C: `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int))` , C++ : `int *p = new int ()`  . The rest is the same exept for `printf`

Comment: Your idea was valid, though. The way to express it in C would be something like `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Comment: @EEAH More accurately `int *p; if (!(p=malloc(sizeof(*p))) return 1;` considering that `malloc` may fail in which case the subsequent `*p` would result `UB`. C++'s exception thrown in case of a failure in `new` takes care of that implicitly.

Comment: @PSkocik Yes. Edited the answer